# Oracle Trigger creation with compilation errors, ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Tags: oracle, triggers, sequence

When I generate the SQL using PowerDesigner and run it in Oracle, it throws the error

> Warning:Trigger creation with compilation errors

```
create trigger "tib_material_classify" before insert
on "material_classify" for each row
declare
    integrity_error  exception;
    errno            integer;
    errmsg           char(200);
    dummy            integer;
    found            boolean;

begin
    --  column ""id"" uses sequence material_classify_seq;
    select material_classify_seq.nextval into :new."id" from dual;

--  errors handling
exception
    when integrity_error then
       raise_application_error(errno, errmsg);
end;
```

When I issue `show errors` in Oracle, it says the following:

> 10/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   10/12    PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "sequence does not exist" means the sequence does not exist. That is, your schema does not have a sequence called `material_classify_seq`. Either you have not created such a sequence or it has a different name from the one referenced in your trigger code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before create trigger you need create sequnce
`Create sequence  material_classify_seq start with 1;` after create trigger

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that sequence `material_classify_seq` is missing. You can create the missing sequence with the following SQL statement:

```
Create Sequence material_classify_seq;
```

Comment: I'm glad the command helped. Since your problem is solved, please mark this as the accepted answer.